# Plotting feature weight for PCA analysis

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, pca, variance

I have a set of data that is accessible on:

http://textuploader.com/df5nt

There are 4 columns in my data set corresponding to 4 different features.
I can calculate the first and second principal components using this code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA as sklearnPCA
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

data = pd.read_csv('rr.txt')
X = data.ix[:,0:4].values
X_std = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)
sklearn_pca = sklearnPCA(n_components=2)
Y_sklearn = sklearn_pca.fit_transform(X_std)

print (Y_sklearn)
```

Now I want to draw the **features weights** for these data. Something like this:
[features weight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPC2r.png)

I know I need to use the **explained variance ratio** in scikit-learn but I could not figure out how to implement it in my code to get it. I was hoping if someone could help me with that.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

use components_ attribute

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html

```
feature_weights = sklearn_pca.components_
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2)
ax1.bar(range(4),feature_weights[0],color=['b','g','r','c'])
ax2.bar(range(4),feature_weights[1],color=['b','g','r','c'])
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. How can I write the "explained variance" on top of each graph like the image in my question? It seems like I have to use "explained variance ratio" for this purpose but I could not figure it out.